# Cant get mongoose-unique-validator to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

it cant be that difficult, but I'm always getting the default mongoose 11000 error.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

`model`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    uniqueCaseInsensitive: true,
    required: true
  }
});
UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
```

`controller`

```
var data = {email: 'info@foobar.com'};
var user = new User(data);
user.save(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

but then I'm always getting this

```
{
  "code": 11000,
  "index": 0,
  "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: portfolio:27017.users index: email_1 dup key: { : \"info@foobar.com\" }",
  "op": {
    "email": "info@foobar.com",
    "_id": "58de95892be2a000d27ee3bc",
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

instead of something like this

```
{
    message: 'Validation failed',
    name: 'ValidationError',
    errors: {
        username: {
            message: 'Error, expected `username` to be unique. Value: `JohnSmith`',
            name: 'ValidatorError',
            kind: 'mongoose-unique-validator',
            path: 'username',
            value: 'JohnSmith'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need it.
Actually, unique option for validation working,how?
Follow these steps:
1)set unique: true for certain field in schema(example "email")
2)drop whole db
3)restart node server
4)test in postman and you will see than now works

Cheers.

Comment: After having twice edited the same for formatting, I have to ask you to try posting less similar answers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64192754/7733418