# mongoose : find data by looping on an array of models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm getting stuck on an asynchronous algorithm :

I've an array of mongoose models :

```
var allRefDatasSchemas = {
  RefAllotement: mongoose.model('RefAllotement', RefDataSchema),
  RefModeleConstructeur: mongoose.model('RefModeleConstructeur', RefDataSchema),
  RefTypeKit: mongoose.model('RefTypeKit', RefDataSchema),
  RefTypeUtilisation: mongoose.model('RefTypeUtilisation', RefDataSchema),
};
```

I'd like to grab all items of each collection and put them in an array or something like that.
If I do that, the `this` keyword of the `find` callback doesn't refer to the current model,
so impossible for me to know which model items belong to

```
var results = {};

for (var model in allRefDatasSchemas) {

  allRefDatasSchemas[model].find(function(err, data) {

    // I'd like to do something like that :
    // but this.modelName is null, because it isn't the model
    // on which the find is done.
    results[this.modelName] = data;

    // if I use "model" variable, it doesn't work, because asynchronous callback

  });

}
```

I've also tried [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) library without success, because I always return to the same issue : impossible to know which model execute the find query inside the callback.
Idem in a `then` if I use promises.

Please help me :) How would you do that ?

EDIT
model.find calls query.find, query.find calls mquery.find. In mquery.find, callback is called, by lost the this reference a that time : this._collection.find(conds, options, utils.tick(callback));
/EDIT

Comment: You can edit your own question to add information rather than post comments. I really don't understand why you would want to do this as surely you can model in a different way. But `async` series should work for you, except that is not the code you have posted.

Comment: Yes, I understand your question about the modeling : my goal is to load some refdata (data used in select inputs) at a time on a backbone client app (to follow [this pattern](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#bootstrapping_data) ) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this code snippet, I have made a working sample of what you need.
**Please check comments in the code for better understanding.**

[Sample Working code](https://gist.github.com/harpreetkhalsagtbit/a3eeadd5c6e99650f667) similar to what you required. Another [ref ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181248/making-mongoose-js-queries-run-synchronously/17296329#17296329) for using async with mongoose.

```
/*
 * Object to store all models
 */
var allRefDatasSchemas = {
  RefAllotement: mongoose.model('RefAllotement', RefDataSchema),
  RefModeleConstructeur: mongoose.model('RefModeleConstructeur', RefDataSchema),
  RefTypeKit: mongoose.model('RefTypeKit', RefDataSchema),
  RefTypeUtilisation: mongoose.model('RefTypeUtilisation', RefDataSchema),
};
/*
 * need an array to run all queries one by one in a definite order using async waterfall mwthod
 */
var arr = [];
for(each in allRefDatasSchemas) {
    arr.push(each);
}

/*
 * Callback function for initiation of waterfall
 */
var queue = [
    function(callback) {
        // pass the ref array and run first query by passing starting index - 0
        callback(null, arr, 0)
    }
];

/*
 * Object to store result of all queries
 */
var finalResult = {};

/*
 * Generic Callback function for every dynamic query
 */
var callbackFunc = function(prevModelData, currentIndex, callback) {
    allRefDatasSchemas[arr[currentIndex]].find(function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {

            // Your Query
            // 
            // I'd like to do something like that :
            // but this.modelName is null, because it isn't the model
            // on which the find is done.

            // arr[currentIndex] will point to 
            // RefAllotement, RefModeleConstructeur etc. as you required
            finalResult[arr[currentIndex]] = result

            // send current result to next interation if required or you can skip
            // and increment the currentIndex to call next query 
            callback(null, result, currentIndex + 1)
        }
    })
}

/*
 * Add callback function for every dynamic query
 */
for(each in allRefDatasSchemas) {
    queue.push(callbackFunc);
}

/*
 * Run all dynamic queries one by one using async.js waterfall method
 */
async.waterfall(queue, function (err, result) {
    // Final object with result of all the queries
    console.log('finish', finalResult)
});
```

**output** will be in this format

```
finish { RefAllotement:[
        // Result of RefAllotement query
    ],
    RefModeleConstructeur:[
        // Result of RefModeleConstructeur query
    ],
    RefTypeKit:[
        // Result of RefTypeKit query
    ],
  RefTypeUtilisation:[
        // Result of RefTypeUtilisation query
    ]
}
```

Comment: Amazing ! The only thing I was missing was to create a second array with indexed model's names ! with it, I can know the modelName in the find callback (`finalResult[arr[currentIndex]] = result`). Thanks a lot for you clear response !

Comment: Thanks to you too, My first question accepted in StackOverflow