# how can I create a auto-increment field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-auto-increment

can any one tell me how can I create a auto-increment field in mongoose without using any library or plugin. Any simple and easy way..

Comment: please have a look
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30164636/1530987

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a very simple and easy way to implement auto increment in mongoose by using **mongoose pre save** function. Here are my codes for user collection, try the same trick in your **mongoose model(schema)** to implement auto increment. Paste this code in your collection schema file and **replace some variables**(*userSchema, user*) **according to your collection schema**.

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    this.updated_at = currentDate;

    if (!this.created_at)
        this.created_at = currentDate;

    var sno = 1;
    var user = this;
    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;
        sno = users.length + 1;
        user.sno = sno;
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not a valid solution. If entry gets deleted from the middle that there will be same id for multiple entry as you are taking the length of document and increasing by 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357965/mongoose-auto-increment

Comment: In my case, I was using the soft delete functionality so it didn't occur.

Comment: I'm adding another answer to give you more solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are **using soft delete functionality** **above answer may work** but to solve it, there are several ways.
1: Before inserting a new record fetch the last document(row) and put `id = 1 + (id of the last record)`.
2: **You can use plugin** [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment).
3: **Last but not least** option save the last incremented value in a separate collection(collection name: `autoIncrement` columns will be collection and sno), before creating a record fetch the sno value of that collection increment it, create your record and update the sno value again in autoIncrement collection.

**Bonus:**

1: You can create autoIncrement in redis.

2: The first point of this answer will not able to solve several problems, ie: Your app will do kind of behavior on deletion, if user delete a row from start or middle of your collection, it will remove that id(that sno. form table), but in case the user deletes the last record. It will put that sno. in next record.

```
var CounterSchema = Schema({
    _id: {type: String, required: true},
    seq: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
var counter = mongoose.model('counter', CounterSchema);

var entitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    testvalue: {type: String}
});

entitySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var doc = this;
    counter.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: 'entityId'}, {$inc: { seq: 1} }, function(error, counter)   {
        if(error)
            return next(error);
        doc.testvalue = counter.seq;
        next();
    });
});
```