# How do I define a different primary key other than _id in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to define Mongoose schemas with primary keys that are not `_id`. The documentation says it only allows the schema options flag `_id` to be set to false in subdocuments. Also, I want the primary key to be a `String` and not an `ObjectId`. Is that possible at all?

Using a secondary index is an option, but not a very good one since I want to have primary keys with proper names. I also don't want to fiddle around with two different indexes when I don't need to.

This sets `documentId` as a secondary index but that makes the primary key useless since I want to only select by `documentId` and not whatever `_id` ends up being set to automatically.

```js
const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
  documentId: { type: String, index: true }
})
```

I want to do something like

```js
const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
  documentId: String
})
```

and then tell it to use `documentId` as the primary key.

**Clarification**: I specifically don't want to use the `_id` as a key since it has an unhelpful name and I want to use `documentId` as the primary key instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could manually define `_id` field during the schema stage, like:

```
const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String //or number, or (increment) function,
  ...
  other_field: BSON_type,
})
```

**Updated Nestjs**

To manually override or define `_id` field in schema use this example:

```
/**
 * extends Document is a Mongoose Document from 'mongoose'
 * and don't forget about Nest Schema decorator
 */
@Schema()
export class Key extends Document { 
  @Prop({ type: String }) // also can be Number, or Decimal128
  _id: string; // number

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  secret: string;
}
```

Disabling `_id` for subdocument in `@Prop` via `@Prop({ _id: false })`

If you are looking for an array of embedded docs with `_id` example, you [might wanna take a look at my other question about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044809/nestjs-mongoose-schema-decorators-with-array-subdocument-field-without-defau)

And add `_id` value to your document before the `insert` stage or generate it via your function, or `npm` module like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-generate-unique-key) at the `schema` part. The only thing that you should make sure of, that your custom generated `_id` values must be unique. If they won't, mongo returns you an error, during inserting document w/o unique `_id` value.

Comment: I already have a way of generating document ids, I just want to store them in a field called `documentId` and not `_id`. But if that isn't possible, is it ok to define _id as type String instead?

Comment: @douira I just added this part to the answer, haven't seen `clarification` part of the question before.

Comment: Probably my fault, I thought the question made it clear that I wanted to call it `documentId` and not `_ id`.

Answer (score 4):

In MongoDB, there is no primary key.

All you need is an `unique: true` index and you’re good to go.

```
const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
  _id: false,
  documentId: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  }
})
```

See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

> A unique index ensures that the indexed fields do not store duplicate
>   values; i.e. enforces uniqueness for the indexed fields. By default,
>   MongoDB creates a unique index on the _id field during the creation of
>   a collection.

Comment: oh so I only need to define a secondary index, make is unique and then I have something like a primary index?

Comment: Yes, correct. Have a bunch of these in my projects. That being said, this will break `Model.findById`. You will have to query things using `Model.findOne({ documentId: 'unique_key' })`.

Comment: @douira Yeah, that's it, but don't forget that if you import your doc w/o that field, mongo will return you an error, so I highly recommend you something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357965/mongoose-auto-increment. That will generate your custom_id during schema.

Comment: It’s my understanding that `_id` is more of a convention than a primary key. Following conventions is usually a good idea though when using the work of others. I usually set `_id: false` for subdocuments that I don't need to query.

Comment: Don't I need to also set `index: true` in the field options for `documentId`?

Comment: @douira No, `unique: true` creates the index for you. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: @douira "A unique index ensures that the indexed fields do not store duplicate values; i.e. enforces uniqueness for the indexed fields. By default, MongoDB creates a unique index on the _id field during the creation of a collection."

Comment: I have found out that all documents must have a `_id` key for mongoose to work. mongoose will error if there is no such key. I have now simply declared the `_id` field as a String.

Answer (score 4):

```
const Schema = new Schema({
  _id: false,
  Id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    index: true,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Indexing would be the best way to do it. Infact, _id is also an index. Try creating an index like:

```
documentSchema.index({ 'documentId' : 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Refer : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/