# mongodb query events done to an item and group them into an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know that the title might be a bit vague, but I will elaborate here.

basically what I am trying to achieve is the following:

I have a collection with documents that have the following scheme:

```
bookId: <uuid>
genre: <string>
isTaken: true
historyIndex: each time something happens i increment this 
returnedAt: not required but will be present on documents with historyIndex
takenAt: not required but will be present on documents with historyIndex
```

there are documents with no `historyIndex` field because they are representing the book itself without the action that were done to the book.

what i want to do is this:

I want to query the books by their unique uuid and then use the documents with `historyIndex` and add them to the main documents as in an array as called `bookEvents`

so the final results will be

```
bookId:
bookEvents: [] --> an array with all the entries that contain history index
```

basically everytime the status of the book changes, i am inserting an event with the date it was taken on and the date it was returned on

What would be the best way of achieving such thing ?

Should I query once and iterate in my code ?
Should I query twice (once where the fields exist and once where they don't) ?

Thank you in advance for all the people that will try to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin or events to achieve this.

```
var CounterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {type: String, required: true},
    seq: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
var counter = mongoose.model('counter', CounterSchema);

var entitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    sort: {type: String}
});

entitySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var doc = this;
    counter.findByIdAndUpdateAsync({_id: 'entityId'}, {$inc: { seq: 1} }, {new: true, upsert: true}).then(function(count) {
        console.log("...count: "+JSON.stringify(count));
        doc.sort = count.seq;
        next();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("counter error-> : "+error);
        throw error;
    });
});
```

> refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40137723/8201020

Comment: Hey, but if ill query the book by the Id will i get all the events in an array ?