# Embedding a Sequelize promise into a javascript async/await chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, sequelize.js

I am trying to use a Sequelize promise inside of an existing async/await chain.  Sequelize returns everything as a promise.  I am new to promises and async/await
so I am using this as something of a learning experience.  Please be extra patient with me.

My logic looks like this:

> if row does not exist from previous '.then'
>
> > create a new row and extract the new id
>
> else
>
> > extract id value from previous '.then'

So now I have a ***WORKING*** block of code now (below), from studying many excellent SO examples.  I want to use all anonymous functions since IMHO it makes it a little bit easier to read.  (yes debatable point, but for now I want to try getting this working with anonymous functions.

It seems odd to have *three* nested return statements.  Is there a way to rewrite this block of code to be a bit cleaner but just using anonymous functions?

```
yourTable.findAll( {...})
.then( (data) => {
      // more code
})
.then( (data) => {
      // more code
})
.then( (data) => {
     if  ( !Array.isArray(data) || !data.length ) {  
           // if record does NOT exist
         return (async function ()       {
             return await
                 (function ()    {
                     return new Promise( resolve => {
                         myTable.create( { ........ }
                            ).then( (result) => {
                                resolve(result._id);
                        })
                    })
                })();
            })()    
            /* we had to create one, so we return the *NEW* _id value */
    } else {
            /* we found one, so we just return the pre-existing _id value */                                                                                      
        return  data[0]._id    ;
    }
})
.then( (data) => {
    // more code
})
.then( (data) => {
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promises are just values which can be `await`ed but you actually don't strictly *need* to `await` them, especially if your surrounding structure isn't using `async`/`await`. You could write it like this:

```
yourTable.findAll({ /* ... */ })
    .then((data) => {
        if (!Array.isArray(data) || !data.length) {
            // We need to create one, return the new ID
            return myTable.create({ /* ... */ })
                .then((result) => result._id)
        } else {
            // We found one, return the existing ID
            return data[0]._id
        }
    })
```

If you return a Promise from within a `.then()` it will become part of the parent chain which is probably exactly what you want.

If you *really* want to use `async`/`await`, then I would recommend flipping the logic and doing the larger work after your happy path is accounted for like so:

```
yourTable.findAll({ /* ... */ })
    .then(async (data) => {
        if (data && data.length) return data[0]._id

        const result = await myTable.create({ /* ... */ })

        return result._id
    })
```

Comment: where the **** were you yesterday?  you would have saved me several hours of useless research.   but seriously, thank you very much.  my logic i am following is a bit odd since i have to read one of the table twice, however your first suggestion worked perfectly and made the code far more readable.  i am surprised a situation like this does not occur more frequently.  you should publish your excellent suggestion somewhere, and not just here.

Answer (score 2):

Drop all the unnecessary [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-iife-construct-in-javascript), [IIAFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40745153/1048572), the [`return await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/1048572) and the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it):

```
if (!Array.isArray(data) || !data.length) {
    // if record does NOT exist
    const result = await myTable.create({ ........ });
    return result._id; // we had to create one, so we return the *NEW* _id value 
} else {
    return data[0]._id; // we found one, so we just return the pre-existing _id value
}
```

Comment: that was the first thing i tried, and i got this back:
"SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Comment: Sure, you would need to use an `async (data) => {` callback to your `then` function of course. But really you shouldn't mix `then` and `await` syntax, rather make the outer function use `async`/`await` as well - can you show us more code?

Comment: Or if you don't want to use `await`, it should be a simple `return myTable.create({…}).then(result => result._id);` in the `if` block.

Comment: "rather make the outer function"  - ok you have my attention...!  and i added more code, but its really not much else to it.

Comment: You should probably start with `const data = await yourTable.findAll( {...}); // more code` etc. Then for the `if`/`else`, when you cannot just `return`, assign to variable (or use a conditional operator). Put all this in an `async` function (or, if it already is inside a function, add the `async` keyword to that).

Comment: i had to look up what IIFE and IIAFE meant.    thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @edwardsmarkf That's why I put links on them in the answer :-)