# Async/await syntax: Is there a way to define a block of code to execute after a function without blocking the execution?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I've been questionning myself recently on how to reproduce a behaviour of then/catch with an async/await syntax.

With then/catch, I can define a callback which is only executed when the Promise resolves and then continue the execution like so .

```
function test() {
    getUsersFromDB().then(users => console.log(users));
    console.log('The rest of the code here continues to execute');
    [...]
    // Promise resolves and logs the users value
}
```

For me, with async/await you can have 2 possible behaviours.

**1. Wait for the function and block the rest of the execution**

```
async function test() {
   const users = await getUsersFromDB();
    // Code in here is not executed until promises returns
    console.log(users);
}
```

**2. Don't wait for the return value but don't expect you promise to be fulfilled when the rest of the code executes**

```
function test() {
    const users = getUsersFromDB();
    // May log undefined
    console.log(users);
}
```

Can I reproduce the first use case using async/await ?

Comment: What about good old `try/catch` with version 1?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Like `let users; try { users = await getUsersFromDB(); } catch (e) { console.error(e); } console.log(users);`

Answer (score 1):

Using `then` is the simplest solution, but you can use an [AIIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40745153/1048572):

```
function test() {
    (async () => {
         const users = await getUsersFromDB();
         console.log(users);
    })().catch(console.error);
    console.log('The rest of the code here continues to execute');
    [...]
    // Promise resolves and logs the users value
}
```

An alternative could only be [`async do` expressions](https://github.com/inexorabletash/ecmascript-async-do-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is basically split the code. One piece should be executed in async/await syntax, and another one should be as usual.

First what I want to say, if you do as follows

```
async function test() {
   console.log('The rest of the code here continues to execute');   
   const users = await getUsersFromDB();
   // Code in here is not executed until promises returns
   console.log(users);
}
```

that will do the trick. This may appear a little strange because we just moved the line a bit up, this is not what we wanted to do, but...

The `await` keyword stops execution of an `async` function, but we have some code that should continue working at the time when `await` freezes the function, that means we can't place the code after `await`, only before.

As far as I understand, the code tahat is indicated as "The rest of the code here continues to execute" can be asynchronous too, so the resulting example will be as follows:

```
async function test() {
   console.log('Some synchronous code');   

   setImmediate(() => { 
       console.log('Some asynchronous code'); 
   });

   const users = await getUsersFromDB();
   // Code in here is not executed until promises returns
   console.log(users);
}
```