# Event listener not working after elements are rendered in the dom

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I am creating a project that when I click a certain category card I get the id of that category and redirect to movies screen.

I am aware that the **row.eventlistener()** in index.js it will be executed before the elements are rendered and that is why it does not pick the id. How should I add the event listener to each newly rendered item before adding it to the container so that I can get the id for each category card.

index.js

```
async function getCategories() {
  let url = 'http://localhost:8080/movieCategories';
  try {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}


async function renderCategories() {
  let categories = await getCategories();
  let html = '';
  categories.forEach(category => {


    let htmlSegment = `
            <div class="category-card" id=${category.id}>
            <img src="./assets/images/sci-fi.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
            <div class="name">${category.name}</div>
          </div>
        `;
    html += htmlSegment;
  });
  let container = document.querySelector('.category-grid');
  container.innerHTML = html;
}

 renderCategories();


document.querySelectorAll('div.category-card').forEach(row=>{
  row.addEventListener('click',event=>{
    console.log('Category clicked', event.currentTarget.id)
    window.location= 'movies.html?categoryId=' +event.currentTarget.id;
  });

});
```

index.html

```
<section class="category" >
  <h2 class="section-heading">Category</h2>
  <div class="category-grid">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have tried to put the event listener logic inside but still did not work .In which place exactly inside and how ?

Comment: So odd you are reinventing html anchors

Comment: The OP wants to register a single event handler exactly once at the root node (which is ... `document.querySelector('.category-grid')`) and then make use of [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Any content inside of the root node can be removed / replaced / inserted at will without any additional event listening tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also just add the event on the div itself directly when you create it and pass the id or whatever you want.

```
<div class="category-card" id=${category.id} onclick="onCatClick(${category.id})">
```

After this, you can move your logic inside a top level `onCatClick` function.

```
function onCatClick(id) {
    console.log('Category clicked', id)
    window.location= 'movies.html?categoryId=' + id;
}
```

This is if your styling/layout doesn't allow you to use an anchor element. Otherwise, you could simply replace the div with an anchor element:

```
<a href="movies.html?categoryId=${id}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting the call to `renderCategories`, move your event listener logic inside the `renderCategories` method OR You could use an immediately invoked async function expression or IIAFE for short, more about this here [immediately-invoked-async-function-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745153/es8-immediately-invoked-async-function-expression):

```
    (async () => {
        await renderCategories();
        document.querySelectorAll('div.category-card').forEach(row => {
           row.addEventListener('click', event => {
               console.log('Category clicked', event.currentTarget.id)
               window.location= 'movies.html?categoryId=' +event.currentTarget.id;
           });
        });
    })();
```

Comment: Not working solution.

Comment: @UserGAmsterdam Then you aren't using it correctly. This will work. You'll need to use this function after the DOM is loaded. Perhaps you need to wrap it in `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...`

Comment: There are errors in the brackets . Havent seen it before thats why I dont know how to use it.

Comment: @UserGAmsterdam There was a missing single quote, typo on my part, try updated.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```js
async function getCategories() {
  let url = 'http://localhost:8080/movieCategories';
  try {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}


async function renderCategories() {
  let categories = await getCategories();
  let html = '';
  categories.forEach(category => {


    let htmlSegment = `
            <div class="category-card" id=${category.id}>
            <img src="./assets/images/sci-fi.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
            <div class="name">${category.name}</div>
          </div>
        `;
    html += htmlSegment;
  });
  let container = document.querySelector('.category-grid');
  container.innerHTML = html;
}
 //es8
await renderCategories();

// fix timeout async render element
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('div.category-card').forEach(row=>{
    row.addEventListener('click',event=>{
      console.log('Category clicked', event.currentTarget.id)
      window.location= 'movies.html?categoryId=' +event.currentTarget.id;
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: It does not work