# How to use a synchronous queries with mongoose on NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, mongoose, synchronous

I tried to make a synchronous queries using mongoose ODM  using 'await' keyword basing on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181248/making-mongoose-js-queries-run-synchronously) as the example bellow :

```
 const query= userModel.find({});
 const syncResutlt= await query.exec();
 console.log(syncResutlt);
```

but I got this error message :

```
  const result2 = await query.exec();
                        ^^^^^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I tried also `yield` generator keyword, but I get always the same error 
`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

for information I have nodeJs V8.

Answer (score 3):

You can only await Promises or a function marked as async, which essentially returns a Promise.

**Correct Way**

```
let getUser=async function(user_id){
    let info= await User.findById(user_id);
    console.log(info); // contains user object
}
```

**Incorrect Way**

```
let getUser= function(user_id){
    let info= await User.findById(user_id); //will throw an exception on await keyword
    console.log(info); // contains user object
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i mad getUser function return the info object, but when i use it in another function like "let data = getUser(1)" => data = {} (empty object)